# DB2-z/os - Is it possible to use XMLMODIFY in CASE statement

Tags: xml, db2, zos

I have a table with a column of type xml. I want to create a query such that, if xml is null, then set an xml, else add a node to the xml. The query I have is below. Adding a node executes successfully without a CASE statement, but once put in CASE statement it fails. Is there a different way to do a conditional insertion of node?

```
UPDATE 
  MY_DOCS
SET DOC = CASE 
  WHEN DOC is null THEN :DOC
  ELSE XMLMODIFY(
    'declare default element namespace "http://www.example.com/docs"; insert node $new as last into /Document ' ,
    CAST(:NEWNODE AS XML)  as "new")
  END
WHERE ID = '123'
```

Exception

> THE OBJECT XMLMODIFY, SPECIFIC NAME , IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED SQL Code: -390, SQL State: 42887

Comment: Have you tried moving the CASE one level up, e.g., `update my_docs case when doc is null set doc=doc else set doc=xmlmodify...`?

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. I tried it , and it doesn't look like the syntax is accepted. I get the error,                                        ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD WHEN.  TOKEN INCLUDE <END-OF-STATEMENT> QUERYNO SKIP WITH SET WHERE WAS EXPECTED SQL Code: -199, SQL State: 42601